# Why my result of HtmlUnit Demo is different from the result of web page?

Tags: java

I've made a web page to crack verification code, such as "1867". The web page was coded by HTML5 & Javascript. And when I use explorer to open the page, the result is correct. Then I want to use HtmlUnit to get the result of the web page above. But I find the result is always 8888. Why? My HtmlUnit code likes this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://127.0.0.1:8080/fundtest/demo.html");
HtmlDivision div1=(HtmlDivision)page.getElementById("1");
HtmlDivision div2=(HtmlDivision)page.getElementById("2");
HtmlDivision div3=(HtmlDivision)page.getElementById("3");
HtmlDivision div4=(HtmlDivision)page.getElementById("4");

webClient.closeAllWindows();
System.out.println(div1.asText() + div2.asText() + div3.asText() + div4.asText());
```

The elements such as div1, div2, div3, div4 should be 1, 8, 6, 7. And the explorer such as Chrome shows the result is 1867, but my java result is 8888.

Comment: use print statements to see the value of each component.asText() value. Probably not what you think they are.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use `page.asXml()` to see the result. The result is 8888. But I don't know why it's different from the chrome result. There is a warning message in console -  **window.alert("java.io.IOException: No image detected in response") no alert handler installed**.

Comment: I find maybe the result is the src of canvas has not been loaded. But why ? `var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/fundtest/checkNumber.png";
  
  
  img.onload = function(){...}`